# Symfony 5 bundle services.yaml - no extension able to load the configuration

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I am trying to create a simple custom bundle for Symfony 5. My bundle structure looks like:

```
- SqliteFileBundle
  - src
    - DependencyInjection
      - SqliteFileExtension.php
    - Resources
      - config
        - services.yaml
    - Services
      - SqliteFileDb.php
    - SqliteFileBundle.php
```

Really simple, trivial even.

`SqliteFileExtension.php`:

```
namespace SqliteFile\Bundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

/**
 * SqliteFileExtension
 */
class SqliteFileExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}
```

`Resources/config/services.yaml`:

```
sqlite_file.db:
  public: true
  class: SqliteFile\Bundle\Services\SqliteFileDb
  arguments:
    $dbPath: "%env(resolve:SQLITE_FILE_DB_PATH)%"
```

`SqliteFileBundle.php`:

```
namespace SqliteFile\Bundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

/**
 * SqliteFileBundle
 */
class SqliteFileBundle extends Bundle
{

}
```

When I attempt to load this bundle in to a Symfony 5 app, it fails with:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sqlite_file.db"
Looked for namespace "sqlite_file.db", found "none".
```

No matter what I try, I cannot get this trivial service to load or get around this error. If I take out the YAML load, I can see the bundle is loaded (but obviously defining nothing and doing nothing)...what am I doing wrong please, why can't I define a simple service and have it load?

EDIT: Weirdly, I can get this to work with an equivalent XML config and XML file loader in the extension. Why? Why does the YAML version not work? I'd rather use YAML than XML if possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="sqlite_file.db" class="SqliteFile\Bundle\Services\SqliteFileDb">
            <argument key="$dbPath">%env(resolve:SQLITE_FILE_DB_PATH)%</argument>
        </service>
        <service id="sqlite_file.twig_extension" class="SqliteFile\Bundle\Twig\TwigExtension">
            <argument>sqlite_file.db</argument>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Comment: The default key is derived from the bundle's class name. Try sqlite_file instead of sqlite_file.db. You can also overide this from inside of the bundle class.  The error is actually coming from the application configuration file in config/packages.  Again use sqlite_file instead of sqlote_file.db.

Comment: @Cerad already tried that, same error.

Comment: Okay, weirdly I can get it working with a services.xml but not with the equivalent configuration in YAML, anyone know if there's a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I'm an idiot. Spent about 3 hours chasing my tail and it turns out I just forgot to add `services:` as the root key in my `services.yaml`. Would have helped if the error message had pointed me in that direction, but all my Googling was telling me to make sure I was using the correct snake_cased bundle name, which I was.